# Can anybody help me root my lg-ms690 2.2.2

Tags: rooting

I need help rooting my lg ms690 2.2.2. I have tried to get the root kit for my phone but all the links seem to be not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you can root your Android phone. Here are 4 apps you can download to root your phone without the use of a PC:

- [King Root](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/BINQDCEF/%22King%20Root%22)
- [Frameroot](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/SFHSIVED/)
- [Towel Root](https://userscloud.com/arubjkbort69%22iRoot%22)
- [iRoot](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/FJEOEVMZ/)

Good Luck Rooting!!

Overall [link](http://onhax.net/tag/how-to-root-android/) of all apps (You might have to reload the webpage if it shows up as error)